# HDD not initialized on Windows 10

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, mbr

To continue on the saga that [this question](https://superuser.com/posts/comments/2536897?noredirect=1) originated, I'm having the final problem.

The computer recognizes the disk, but it does not work still. Bellow, I'll put a picture of how it's been showing on disk management:

Disk 0 is the SSD, and disk 1 is the HDD. The labels mean "Unknown" and "Not initialized"

[image]

If I try to initialize it, this shows up:

[image]

In English the Windows error reads

> Virtual Disk Manager
>
> The request could not be performed because of an I/O device error.

Comment: Sounds like the HDD is not functioning.  A functional HDD would not prevent a device from booting

Comment: Yeah I guess this is the truth I have been avoiding

Comment: Try to [Initialize new disks](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/disk-management/initialize-new-disks).

Comment: @harrymc - The author already has done that… they get an error…the error specified in their question

Comment: @Ramhound: I wanted to be sure that this is what he did.

Comment: An I/O error usually occurs due to three things, in order of likelihood: Failing HDD - install `smartmontools` on [Windows](https://www.smartmontools.org/wiki/Download#InstalltheWindowspackage) and perform [Steps 3.1 - 3.5](https://superuser.com/a/1482583/529800) _(ignore 1 - 3)_; Bad SATA/SAS cable: swap in a known good cable; Failing motherboard SATA/SAS port: run the built-in BIOS/UEFI hardware diagnostics

Answer (score 2):

If you cant initialize the disk or do anything in Windows to get it working, I would try [GParted](https://gparted.org/).  Download the ISO and write it to a USB drive using [Etcher](https://www.balena.io/etcher/) of [Rufus](https://rufus.ie/), then boot off of it.  Write a new MBR and partition table.  It could not hurt to create a NTFS filesystem and format it, white you are there.  Then boot back into Windows and see if the disk is usable.

Comment: Note though; after having the disk work again; re-initialize (reformat) the disk under the OS you intend to use it with. I believe this ensures that all partitioning data (metadata) ONLY THEN is arranged such that anomalies are avoided to highest possible extent. I have numerous times over the years experienced situations where this has been necessary => INTENT: use the driver which you intend to use it under for ALL operations.

Comment: One more thing: If the partitioning is dropped at any stage of use; scrap the disk, it most likely has some kind of problem recording and KEEPING the metadata; i.e. it is at early stages of wearing out.

Comment: https://www.thomas-krenn.com/en/wiki/Analyzing_a_Faulty_Hard_Disk_using_Smartctl

Comment: @Hannu AFAIK, the formatted filesystem parameters don't change when formatted via `DiskPart` [Windows] versus `ntfs-3g` or other utility [Linux], so I'm unsure why the recommendation is there. Also, why toss a drive without first [verifying](https://superuser.com/questions/1657779/hdd-not-initialized-on-windows-10#comment2538259_1657779) where the problem is at?

Comment: As you apparently have located the problem to be with the drive itself; why bother with it; already that is reason enough to either "toss it", or use it only for playing with. To find out WHY it failed might be a valid thing to work on, but nothing else really. But then, without knowing a lot of detail about the internal technological details, you will not be likely to identify the actual problem easily.